# C# setting case constant expressions, do they have to follow a specific order?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Say I'm making a simple program, and the user is in the menu.

And the menu options are 1 3 5 7 (i wouldn't actually do that but lets just go with it).

and I want to make my switch statement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DecisionMaking2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option: ");
            string SelectedOpt = Console.ReadLine();
            double Selection = Convert.ToDouble(SelectedOpt);

            double MenuOption = (Selection);

            switch (MenuOption)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selected option #1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selected option #3");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selected option #5");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selected option #7");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please choose from the options List!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

would that work? or would I have to name each case constant expression the option number I am using?

I went to the microsoft website and I didn't quite pick up on anything i was looking for. .

Also while I have your attention, how would I make it so the user chooses from either option and because I don't know which option the user will select " double MenuOption = " could be anything, whatever the user inputs right? so would what I have even work?

I am doing this all by hand, and don't get much lab time to work on this as I have tons of other courses to work on and then a boring job to go to, and my PC at home has a restarting issue lol.

soo any and all help is greatly appreciated.

p.s the computer I'm on right now posting this, doesn't have any compilers, coding programs, and it's not mine just to get that out of the way.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the default statement would get fired for the ones you didn't include: 5, 7 or whatever the user inputted.

Comment: so basically the case "number" that I have, like 3 and 4 should be 5 and 7, and that way the user if the user does select it, it will process?

Comment: They'll all "process". The 5 & 7 just won't have a specified case, so they'll fall through until they hit default. If you want them to do something specific, you have to give them a case. If you don't want them to do anything, leave out the default or just include break; as the statement in the case. The order doesn't matter, either.

Comment: alright, I think i get it now, thanks Yatrix, also, does my work make sense? If I want to get the user's input, but I don't know what it will be, would double MenuOption = Selection work? and then based on what Selection is, it'll choose from one of the cases, or default.

Comment: Happy to help. Think of a switch like a short-hand if-else statement. It reads: `If the value = 1, do this, else-if the value = 2, do this, else-if the value = 3, do this`, etc.

Comment: Outstanding, thanks! I never realized how hard it would be to do all this without a computer and some coding software lol. I get why my professor wants us to do it by hand all the time before we hit the computer. Again thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your code probably won't work, or even worse sometimes it might work, sometimes it won't.

You should change the data type for MenuOption and Selection from double to integer.

Doubles inherently have errors in them so you'll probably get cases where your selection goes to default because even though the user has entered "1" when you parse it you might end up with something like MenuOption = 1.000001 or MenuOption = 0.999998

Also you should read up on coding standards.  Have a look at IDesign C# Coding standard....

http://www.idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1985

Answer (score 1):

I would break that into two different methods. Do a while loop with bool. If any of the conditions is selected, that bool is true and the loop breaks.

EDIT.. just to make it clearer:

Set bool flag to false. 
Then create a while loop. 
Get input in the main method. 
If user entered value is 1,3,5,7 then set flag to true, break the loop. No more console readline.
If say 4, continue with the while loop, get user input.. and check again..

**I am not saying don't do the switch statement. Your switch statement is still necessary.** If you want the user to eventually enter the correct value, you'd want that to be in a loop. And then break out of it once they do.

Here's a similar answer from another SO post. That sums up my logic.

```
bool validEntry;
int Selection = 0;
do
{
Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option: ");
        string SelectedOpt = Console.ReadLine();
        validEntry = int.TryParse(SelectedOpt , out Selection);
       if (!validEntry)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Entry must be an integer.");
       }

        int MenuOption = (Selection);

        switch (MenuOption)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Selected option #1");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Selected option #3");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Selected option #5");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Selected option #7");
                break;
            default: 
               validEntry = false; //need to make this false again.
                break;
        }


if (!validEntry)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose from the options List!");
}
} while (!validEntry);
```

Comment: This should be a comment in the question as it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Tejaswi totally forgot about bool, thanks for the suggestion. Doing a while loop in C#, is it the same as doing them in C? if so then I should be fine.

Comment: while(!flag){
 ...
// set flag to true if the value is 1,3,5,7.. this breaks the loop
 
}

Comment: that makes perfect sense actually (had to look up the flags enum attribute to understand it), thanks Tejaswi

Comment: ah interesting, i think i get it. the if(!validentry) is basically taking the opposite value of what its being used on right?

Comment: By default bool is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write something like this (that's provided I understood your question correct):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option: ");
string selectedOpt = Console.ReadLine();
int option = 0;
if (int.TryParse(selectedOpt, out option))
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
            Console.WriteLine("Selected option {0}", option);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose from the options list!");
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("That's an invalid option");
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try and understand what you did here. So bear with me
so first, you made the if statement (int.TryParse(selectedOpt, out option)
looking up TryParse and out, basically what this statement is doing is it'll take whatever string the user inputs, and returns an integer, im at a loss for what "out" is doing.

if there's no code in between 1357, then that would just be saying the same thing as you chose option 1 3 5 or 7 right? 

and you put the switch statement inside an if, switches are like an if statement so that would be a reason why it works right?

then the rest is just default.

Comment: Ok I'll explain, `int.TryParse` will try to evaluate the input and parse it into an `int` if it returns false means it failed, `out` means that you will provide a variable into the function and expect it to come out with value (if there is no error). The grouped `case` statements basically mean, "in any of those cases I want the same code to be executed".

Comment: "out" means if TryParse is successul option will have that value set.

Comment: this great guys, I really appreciate it, I'm actually enjoying C# (maybe because I'm giving it so much attention lol), but i feel next semester I'm going to do really well with it

So thanks again!

Comment: @Umeed Good luck, programming is the best :) Keep it up.